# Angular mask currency - problems with K for thousands and M for millions

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular mask for currency input defined like this:

```
public currencyInputMask = createMask({
 alias: 'numeric',
 groupSeparator: ',',
 digits: 0,
 digitsOptional: false,
 prefix: '$ ',
 placeholder: '',
 parser: (value: string) => {      
   let result = value.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, "");
   let returnVal = (result && !isNaN(+result)) ? parseInt(result) : '';
   return returnVal;
 }
});
```

Inside a component I am using it like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="blueInput" fxFlex>
    <mat-label>Cash (Checking Accounts/Savings Account)</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="cashControl" [inputMask]="currencyInputMask" autocomplete="off">                         
</mat-form-field>
```

Everything works nice and I read the value from the control like this `cashControl.value`.
I've discovered that if I press K or M the control adds 000 for thousand and 000,000 for million and this is awesome. The problem is that these stay at the UI level and doesn't show up into my control value. My question is what do I have to do to reflect the UI value intro the control value. I use angular 14.

Demo on: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vbpagt

Comment: please share a simple stackblitz!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the stackblitz, please find below my version, where I listen for `keyup` event and then programmatically update the form control since its not working normally!

html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>

<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="top15x2">
  <mat-label>Cash (Checking Accounts/Savings Account)</mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    #cashControl
    formControlName="cashControl"
    (keyup)="keyUp(cashControl)"
    [inputMask]="currencyInputMask"
    autocomplete="off"
  />
  <mat-error *ngIf="formControls['cashControl'].invalid">
    {{ formControls['cashControl'].hasError('min') ? 'Min $0' : '' }}
  </mat-error>

  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end start" fxLayoutGap="20px">
    <button mat-raised-button class="button-submit" style="width:100px">
      Save
    </button>
  </div>
</form>

{{ form.value | json }}
```

ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { createMask } from '@ngneat/input-mask';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  public form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {} //constructor

  get formControls() {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      cashControl: new FormControl<number | null>(null, [Validators.min(0)]),
    });
  } //ngOnInit

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {}

  keyUp(cashControl) {
    console.log(cashControl.value);
    const parsed = parseFloat(
      cashControl.value.replace('$', '').replace(/,/g, '')
    );
    this.form.get('cashControl').setValue(parsed);
  }

  public onSubmit(): void {
    if (this.form.invalid) return;

    console.log(this.formControls.cashControl.value);
  } //onSubmit

  public currencyInputMask = createMask({
    alias: 'numeric',
    groupSeparator: ',',
    digits: 0,
    digitsOptional: false,
    prefix: '$ ',
    placeholder: '',
    parser: (value: string) => {
      let result = value.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, '');
      let returnVal = result && !isNaN(+result) ? parseInt(result) : '';
      return returnVal;
    },
  });
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lbiznr)

Comment: Is not working anymore when I press K or M to add the zeros. And this is like a dirty trick that I can't use it on an app with 100 inputs for currency.

Comment: @DA you need to raise concern with package creator this is the best i can provide

Comment: @DA sorry uploaded the wrong stackblitz, can you check this solution?

Comment: It works but I can't use it as a workaround for a complex project. I will wait, maybe someone else had a similar problem and found an easy fix... like a missing property from config or something. I will ask the question also on the package page. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Not working... still the regular value without the zeros.